# PIL Check pixel that it's on with eval function

Tags: python, transparency, python-imaging-library, rgb, pixel

Is there any way using the `eval` function in PIL to run through all pixels, while checking to see what each value is? The program runs through an image to see if each pixel is a certain rgb, and if it is, then it will turn that pixel into transparency. the `eval` function in PIL seems it would do the job, but can my function that converts the pixels check the value of the pixel it's on? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11):

**Updated**: Ahh, I see what you want to do.  Here is an example using only PIL. It converts all white pixels to red with 50% alpha:

```
import Image

img = Image.open('stack.png').convert('RGBA')
width, _ = img.size
for i, px in enumerate(img.getdata()):
    if px[:3] == (255, 255, 255):
        y = i / width
        x = i % width
        img.putpixel((x, y), (255, 0, 0, 127))

img.save('stack-red.png')
```

[image: original]
[image: converted]

**Orig answer**: Yes, the `Image.eval()` function lets you pass in a function which evaluates each pixel, and lets you determine a new pixel value:

```
import Image
img1 = Image.open('foo.png')
# replace dark pixels with black
img2 = Image.eval(img1, lambda px: 0 if px <= 64 else px)
```

Comment: New pixel value? Hm, I'm not entirely understanding this function, sorry... What I can get out of it though, is that it checks to see if the pixel is less than 64, then if it is, converts it to zero? Am I right? If so, how would you set the pixel value to change from as green? How is "pixel value" found for an image?

Comment: I've added an example which should be closer to what you're looking for.

Comment: *If* performance is an issue:  Isn't `putpixel` much slower than `__setitem__` on the `img.getdata()` object?  In other words: `d=img.getitem()` `for i,px in enumerate(d):` `...` `d[i] = (255,0,0,127)`.

Comment: Also, it doesn't seem to do getitem, like Paul said. attribute error.

Comment: @samplebias Maybe it is good to mention that in Python 3.x the `y = i / width` must be `y = i // width`.

Answer (score 3):

No, `eval` will not pass an RGB tuple to a function.  It maps a function over each band.  You could, however process each band using `eval` and then use an `ImageChops` operation to logically combine the bands and get a mask that will be pixel-tuple specific.

By the way, this could be done much more cleanly and efficiently in NumPy if you are so inclined..

```
import numpy as np
import Image
import ImageChops
im_and = ImageChops.lighter

im = Image.open('test.png')
a = np.array(im)

R,G,B,A = im.split()

color_matches = []
for level,band in zip((255,255,255), (R,G,B)):
    b = Image.eval(band, lambda px: 255-(255*(px==level)))
    color_matches.append(b)

r,g,b = color_matches
mask = im_and(r, im_and(g, b))
im.putalpha(mask)
im.save('test2.png')
```